# What format is this geo string

Tags: format, geocoding, geo

N55.30.3878,E9.44.4944

(The comma may, or may not be part of the format!)

Which format is this? I know the latitude and longitude of this point is:

Latitude: 55.506196666667

Longitude: 9.7416983333333

Also, if you are extra cool and didn't know which format this was by experience, please tell me how you figured out which format it is! I've been googling and pulling my hair for the last 2 hours because of this!

Answer (score 1):

It's degrees, minutes and seconds notation

- N55.30.3878
- N: above equator, positive latitude
- 55: 55 degrees, same as in decimal coords
- 30: 30 minutes, or (30 / 60 )  degrees
- 3878: 38.78 seconds, or (38.78 / 60 ) minutes, or (38.78 / 3600 )  degrees.

.

```
55 + 30/60 + 38.78 / 3600 
55 + 0.5 + 0.0061967
55.5061967
```

The longitude process is pretty much the same

PD: You can find variations of this notation such as

- +50.30.3878
- +50°30'3878"

you can't really deprecate traditional notations, but they are less used because they are less efficient to parse. Most databases would consider above inputs to be just strings.

**Edit**: I was wrong when I assumed lightly that the formula matched your coordinates. I didn't had a calc at hand and switching tasks in my cellphone often leads to lose the answer draft.

So, as you've seen, the degrees + minutes + seconds interpretation +55°30'3878"

translates to 55.51772

And the degrees + decimal minutes interpretation +55°30.3878'

translates to  55.5064633

Regarding the longitude, it either translates to 9.74157 (9°44.4944') or 9.74706 (9°44'4944")

As you can see, none of these alternatives translates to 55.5061967. They don't seem to be one of the [three coordinate formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Coordinate_format_conversion) I know.

I'm sorry my answer misled you.

Comment: :( that was the standard notation when I was a kid

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. If I do the same math with the same numbers, it's quite off. For me, 38.78 / 3600 = 0,0107722222222222

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. It seems I messed up. See my edit